# Triggering an animation on a div by clicking a button using addClass/removeClass with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I'm trying to trigger an animation by clicking on a button using addClass and removeClass with Javascript.

I'm not bad at HTML/CSS but I only strating to learn Javascript by editing snipets.

So here's mine can you tell me why my div won't rotate when I click the black button ?

Thanks in advance !

```
<button class="menu-circle"></button>

<img class='imgblock' src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />

.menu-circle {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: #000000;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transition: .1s;
z-index: 100;
border: none;
}

.menu-circle:hover {
height: 115px;
width: 115px;
}

.menu-circle:active {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}

.imgblock {
display: block;
margin: 20px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
-moz-transition-duration: 1s;
-o-transition-duration: 1s;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

.rotate {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}

$('.menu-circle').on('click', function(){
$('img .imgblock').addClass('rotate');
$('img .imgblock .rotate').removeClass('rotate');
});
```

WORKING FIDDLE :

http://jsfiddle.net/leokaj/rv5PR/366/

Comment: whats the class assignment sequence that you want?? in your code you re trying to select an image with class imgblock while it doesn't exist and also menucircle is different from menu-circle that is in your html

Comment: I've edited my JSfiddle, I had the wrong class on my img sorry !

Comment: In your jsfiddle your circle has the class menu-circle but you're looking for the class menucircle in your selector

Comment: edited as well :) still not working, I've edited all typo problems btw but no triggering yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with your fiddle:

1. Wrong class names: in js `$('.menucircle')` and in html -  `class="menu-circle"`
2. You don't need space between img and class in jquery selector `$('img .imgblock')` - space means you're looking for `.imgblock` class inside the `img` tag (which is impossible).
3. `.current` class is not defined nor in html, nor in css, but appear in js

Here's fiddle where I fixed the problems and which works: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rv5PR/351/)

JS:

```
$('.menu-circle').on('click', function(){
    var $img = $('.crossRotate');
    if (!$img.hasClass('rotate')) {
        $img.addClass('rotate');
    } else {
        $img.removeClass('rotate');
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh this looks great ! sorry for the typo problem again... One question though : why do you have no animation ?

Answer (score 0):

You ve to manage this with 2 different events to animate the image

```
$('.menu-circle').on('mousedown', function(){
    $('.imgblock').addClass('rotate');  
});

$('.menu-circle').on('mouseup', function(){
    $('.imgblock').removeClass('rotate');
});
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3ehcuky5/

if you want to keep the image rotated or not the @alynioke solution is good

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be trying to make it jiggle a bit in animation and you're using jQuery already then I would say you need to look at the .animate() method of teh jQuery library

https://api.jquery.com/animate/